# Home LAN mapping software

Tags: linux, networking, user-interface, lan

I have a pretty simple home LAN: EdgeRouter-x, a couple switches, and a wireless access point. I'd like a dashboard that shows all the computers attached to the network. The EdgeRouter has a DHCP leases view, which basically shows what I want, but it's embedded in the router's UI, and takes a bunch of steps to get to. My previous router was an Asus, and that had a great UI for the network. What I'm looking for, is a stand-alone view that I can install off the router, that gives me a high-level view of the network.

`nmap` provides a lot of what I'd like to read, but it's not exactly user friendly. I'm a software engineer, so my first thought was: "oh, I could run nmap every x minutes, and parse the results into JSON, build a UI, etc, etc" But I have enough side projects, and maybe this is something someone else has already built.

The computer I want to use is Linux, that seems to be a bit of a limiting factor.